# How to compute $\mathbb{E}(X^3)$?

Tags: probability

Suppose $Y=X^2+Z$ where $X$ and $Z$ are independent standard normal random variables.

Hope this question is not too stupid, but how can I show that $E(YX)=0$?

$$
E(YX)=E((X^2+Z)X)=E(X^3+XZ)=E(X^3)+E(XZ)
$$

Now, since $X$ and $Z$ are independent, and $E(X)=E(Z)=0$, I have
$$
E(XZ)=E(X)E(Z)=0.
$$

It remains to compute $E(X^3)$. How can I do so?

What I've already done is to use $V(X)=E(X^2)-E(X)^2$ to get that $E(X^2)=1$.

Maybe one can use that to compute $E(X^3)$?

Comment: This will help https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment-generating_function

Comment: $$E(X^3) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x^3 p(x) dx$$ where $p(x)$ is the probability density function of $X$. If $X$ is zero mean normal, then $p(x)$ is an even function (symmetric around the origin), hence the integrand $x^3 p(x)$ is odd, so the integral is zero.

Comment: For a standard random random variable, $E(X^n)=0$ whenever n is odd.

Comment: @M.T Yes, it does help. The Moment-generating function here is a constant function, viz. $M_X(t)=1$. Hence $E(X^3)=\frac{d^3 M_X}{dt^3}(0)=0$.

Comment: Not, it is not a constant.

Comment: @M.T Oh, sorry. I made a mistake, here, we have $M_X(t)=\exp (0.5 t^2}$. Then the third derivative is $t\cdot (t^2+3)\cdot\exp (t^2/2)$ and for $t=0$ we get $0$.

Answer (score 0):

If the pdf of $X$ is symmetric around the origin, so it is the pdf of $X^3$.

Since $X^3\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ ($e^{-x^2/2}$ is a Schwarz function) it follows that $\mathbb{E}[X^3]=0$.